# Нужно найти длину ключа зашифрованное шифром виженера сообщения используя метод индекса совпадения

Tags: python, криптография, шифрование

Я написал код, который ищет дробит строку и заносит в массив каждый 2, 3, 4 и так далее в зависимости от ключа символ, и ищет индексы совпадений при данной длине ключа, но у меня получаются неверные значения, подскажите пожалуйста где ошибка

```
import textwrap
import collections
##Ввод зашифрованного текста
encrypted_text = input()
##Сглаживание пробелов и знаков препинания
encrypted_text = encrypted_text.replace(' ', '').replace(',', '').replace('.', '').replace('?', '').replace('-', '').replace('!', '')
def index_of_matches(groups_letters):
   IC = 0
   for q in range(len(groups_letters)):
       ##Подсчет количества каждого сивола в строке
       frequency_letters = collections.Counter(groups_letters[q])
       frequency_letters = (sorted(frequency_letters.items()))
       count_letters = []
       ##Отделение чисел 
       count_letters = [list(t) for t in zip(*frequency_letters)][1]
       for r in range(len(count_letters)):
           IC += ((int(count_letters[r])) * int((count_letters[r]) - 1)) / (len(encrypted_text) * (len(encrypted_text) - 1))
   return IC
##Создание массивов по длине ключа
for i in range(2, 10):
   groups_letters = [''] * i
   ##Группировка элементов по массиву
   fragmented_string = textwrap.wrap(encrypted_text, i)
   if len(fragmented_string[-1]) != i:
       fragmented_string[-1] += ' ' * (i - len(fragmented_string[-1]))
   for c in range(len(groups_letters)):
       for z in range(len(fragmented_string)):
           groups_letters[c] += fragmented_string[z][c]
   print(index_of_matches(groups_letters))
```